# how can i disable masonry layout in isotop plugin?

Tags: jquery, masonry, jquery-isotope

I want just use **filtering Option** In `isotop Plugin` . Is it possible to use just filtering Option.
the reason is I want to have **rtl** masonry layout with filtering Option. but isotop dosnt support rtl layout.
but the masonry plugin does.
I want  the isotop do the filtering and the masnroy do the layout.
is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

Isotope does support RTL layout with the isOriginLeft option. All you need to do is set the option:

```
isOriginLeft: false
```

[Here is the documentation](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/options.html#isoriginleft)